# Draw the line "slowly" on a Canvas

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, wpf-controls, line

I have 2 points and I need to draw a line connecting the 2 points. I want the line drawn to be in **slow motion** starting from one point and connecting another point.

Currently, I am using a canvas to draw the line.

```
var line = new Line();
line.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
line.StrokeThickness = 2.0;

line.X1 = 1.0;
line.Y1 = 1.0;
line.X2 = 10.0;
line.Y2 = 10.0;

Canvas.SetRight(myCanvas, From.X);
Canvas.SetBottom(myCanvas, From.Y);
myCanvas.Children.Add(line);
```

Is it possible with any library function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would set the start and end points to be the same, then animate the x,y of the end points using a storyboard.  You can set all sorts of variables on it this way.

Comment: Nice idea! You could even add easing functions.